# What does "Linux Ready" mean in the context of a project written in Swift?

Tags: linux, swift-language

There are few GitHub repositories written in Swift that are presented to be "Linux Ready". The [Zewo organization](https://github.com/Zewo) has several repositories identified as "Linux Ready". What, exactly, does this mean?

Comment: Have you tried asking the maintainers of the software what they mean?

Comment: no, but i thought that is better to ask in forum like this..thinking that is a standard thing.

Comment: I'm reopening. If there is a standard definition of what "Linux Ready" means in the context of Swift, then it can be answered definitively. An answer of "this phrase doesn't have a standard definition" is also a valid answer.

Comment: @ThomasOwens there is nothing from *Apple* what a "Linux ready" swift project means. Anything else is a term used by that project that they made up.

Comment: The [README.md](https://github.com/Zewo/Zeal/blob/master/README.md) for any of the modules the claim to be Linux-ready explains exactly what that means.

Comment: OK, just i needed an answer to this..everyone who has the same question will get his answer here.

Comment: That *one* third party organization is using this term does not make it consistent term used in the industry and should instead be directed at that organization.

Comment: what i got as first understanding..is that these kind of apps will be ready to run in Linux once Swift becomes open source..i want to confirm this first  and if so i want to  get  a brief explanation of it.

Comment: @MejdiLassidi That may be the case, but what systems a given piece of software is supported on is a question to address the maintainers of that software. We can only guess as to what they mean and the amount of support they will provide. Furthermore, this term isn't anything like what Microsoft did with "Windows XYZ ready" branding for their hardware - it isn't something that Apple has given standards for, but rather is something that this product has claimed. The only people who can say what they mean and support is the maintainers of that software. Anything else is guesswork.

Comment: @MichaelT i will ask the repo team, and ask them to give their response here so everybody will have clear idea of the subject..i hope i can get it.

Comment: While that may answer the question for what Zewo means, there is no industry weight behind any interpretation and may be completely wrong if some other organization uses the term "Linux Ready" in a different way.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least according to a quick web search, the expression "Linux ready" does not appear to be some sort of official designation for Swift projects. It looks like only Zewo uses it in that context.

According to the project's [README.md](https://github.com/Zewo/Zeal/blob/master/README.md), it simply means that the project should work under Linux once a Swift implementation is available for Linux:

> Features:
>   No `Foundation` dependency (Linux ready)

So "Linux ready" seems to indicate that the project does not use the [Foundation framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/), which presumable will not become available under Linux in the foreseeable future.

---

Related question from StackOverflow: [Is it possible to build Swift 2.0 code using the Foundation Framework and target linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210648/is-it-possible-to-build-swift-2-0-code-using-the-foundation-framework-and-target)

Answer (score 7):

Linux-ready implies that the project does not contain Apple Foundation frameworks, which would make the project platform specific. Once Apple releases their Swift compiler for Linux - which they announced will be by years end - Linux-ready projects should run "out of the box" on Linux.